# Is it possible to add a Firefox Add-on to Address Bar?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

Just like "Save to Pocket" is it possible to place an add-on icon (like google URL shortener) to the address bar?

This image shows what I mean:

[image]

*I use Firefox Developer Edition 58*

Comment: It depends on the add-on. If it provides a button then yes.

Comment: the add-on is google url shortner and yes it provides a button  
shown in the image 
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/goo-gl-url/

Comment: Hmm. I've just added this extension to FF57 and it added a button to the address bar ... see https://i.imgur.com/t0V2Xz0.png

Comment: Great, my question is can this button be added inside the adress bar my image shows what i mean :) ,just like the Bookmark button !

Comment: Menu > Customise > and see if there is a button you can drag and drop onto the address bar. Otherwise try reinstalling it.

Comment: sure it is the first thing i have tried , no there is no drag and drop onto address bar , anyway thanks for the replay